# netd error when porting ROM

Tags: android

I've been trying to port CM9 from Galaxy Y to s5830i, i know it's better to port from source, but since I don't know how, I'll have to do it this way. Problem is, that when I flash it, i get this error:

E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/NetdConnector( 1455): Communications error
E/NetdConnector( 1455): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:119)
E/NetdConnector( 1455):         at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:88)

I've also been searching for solutions, and some people say its a bug of ICS, and others say that the real problem is in libsysutil.so, so I replaced it with the stock one, but still no luck. I've also replaced netd, but still... I have fixed all problems except that one, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of miss-match of lib files, Generally Happens When Porting .

One more advice for u is Never ever Replace netd of /system/bin Or else Your Rom Won't boot.

Try By swapping libandroid_runtime.so , libwebcore.so